# Client wants following css button

Tags: css, button

I need help in creating following css style for button, Don't know how to add the different backgrounds with spacing between them.

http://i64.tinypic.com/df9936.jpg

Comment: Use a linear-gradient.

Comment: You can use this tool to help you create the gradient https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: I know how to use linear-gradient, But don't know how to achieve the white spacing between different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using css linear gradients. See below example.

```css
button {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border:none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,38,0,1) 0%, rgba(246,41,12,1) 74%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 77%, rgba(255,111,0,1) 78%, rgba(255,111,0,1) 87%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 88%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 89%, rgba(247,255,0,1) 93%, rgba(247,255,0,1) 100%);
}
button:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button>Explore</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Download the image below and name it button-1 then use the html below. The image will be the link and you wont need to play with the white space.

```
<a href="http:www.google.com">
  <img src="button-1.jpg" alt="imagelink" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted?